# Azure AD Bearer token not authorized when POST request Query Usage

Tags: angular, azure, post, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

Good morning.

I am implementing a client in Angular, which has a previous authentication with **Azure AD**, which is defined within Azure to authenticate me.

The login in Angular:

```
login() {
    this.msalService.loginRedirect();
  }
```

When I have successfully logged in, I use the bearer access token to make a POST request to get the charges from my **Azure platform** ([Query Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage#querytimeperiod)) , which needs the bearer as a header.

Once I make the request, it returns a 401 error which gives me the following message:

`401 {"error":{"code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience", "message": "The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource '2cabef09-17b6-48bf-ac80-c4262e7a8101'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'."}}}`

On the other hand, when I make a POST request to get the bearer token, with the following headers, it does generate a bearer access token that allows me to do the Query Usage query.

[POST REQUEST POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0nKu.png)

How can I make this access token valid for other requests?

Comment: You need to request for an access token with the specific resource/scope. An access token is always valid for one API and in this case your token is not valid for the API you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if you generated access token for one scope
> and tried to use it for another scope or audience. So, make sure to
> give value of resource as **`https://management.azure.com/`** and use access token for right resource.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the quota usage successfully like below:***

Before calling the query in Postman, make sure to grant **API permissions** for **`Azure Service Management`** like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Api permissions -> Add a permission -> Azure Service Management***

[image]

**I got the access token successfully using parameters like below:**

[image]

**I called the below query by passing bearer token in `Authorization header` and got the Usage quota successfully:**

[image]

If still the error persists, please check the below **references**:

[Problem when i call a GET REQUEST with an AZURE Token, InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482868/problem-when-i-call-a-get-request-with-an-azure-to.html)

[Receiving InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience error for ListByService endpoint - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/880300/receiving-invalidauthenticationtokenaudience-error.html)